# Run group of tests for each data set from DataProvider sequentially

Tags: java, testng

I need run some test before every data from `DataProvider`.
For example, in sample class below i need run `someStart` Test 4 times (before each data), how to do this?

```
public class Poligon {

    @Test()
    public void someStart(){
        System.out.println("Start");
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData() {
        return new Object[][]{{"a",1},{"c",2},{"d",4},{"x",0}};
    }

    @Parameters({"p","n"})
    @Test(dataProvider = "getData", dependsOnMethods = "someStart")
    public void x(String p, int n){
        String[] a = {"a","b","c","d"};
        int i = 0;
        while( i < a.length && !a[i].equals(p)) i++;
        i = (i < a.length)? i + 1 : 0;
        System.out.println(p + ": " + i);
        Assert.assertEquals(i, n);
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "x", alwaysRun = true)
    public void someEnd(){
        System.out.println("End");
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

I need run like this:

```
Test01 group1
Test02 group1
Test03 group1
DataProvider
Test11 group2 with 1st data set
Test12 group2 with 1st data set
Test13 group2 with 1st data set
Test11 group2 with 2nd data set
Test12 group2 with 2nd data set
Test13 group2 with 2nd data set
...
Test11 group2 with xth data set
Test12 group2 with xth data set
Test13 group2 with xth data set
Test21 group3
Test22 group3
Test23 group3
```

Comment: if you need to call content of someStart() call 4 time put it in 'for' loop. I am not sure why you need to call test 4 times? If this is only for making other test pass, that I think is bad written test. Test should not depend on each other.

Comment: it is only example, i need run some test before test with data provider...

Comment: So like I said before, tests should not depend on each other

Comment: I know that i can concatenate `someStart` and `x`, the problem is that i need split `x` for simplest (more detailed) tests. Is it possible?

Comment: I think you can loop through Object[] [] returned from getData and tested that in someStart test. I mean calli the whatever test you have to on each element of Object[] []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer in this sites: [www.journaldev.com](https://www.journaldev.com/21237/testng-factory-annotation) and [howtodoinjava.com](https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-factory-annotation-tutorial/). But it is't what i exactly need. 
I cant run many groups of test with different `Factory` and without it in expected sequence.

1st: added class with `Factory`
2en: added local variables and constructor in tests class

Factory class:

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test()
public class Poligon2 {

    @Factory(dataProvider = "class-data-provider")
    public Object[] getTestClasses(String s, int n) {
        Object[] tests = new Object[1];
        tests[0] = new Poligon(s, n);
        return tests;
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "class-data-provider")
    public Object[][] getData() {
        return new Object[][]{{"a", 1}, {"c", 3}, {"d", 4}, {"x", 0}};
    }
}
```

Tests class:

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class Poligon {
    final String p;
    final int n;
    int run = 0;
    static int instance = 0;
    final int current_instance;
    static int globalrun = 0;

    public Poligon(String p, int n){
        this.p = p;
        this.n = n;
        instance++;
        current_instance = instance;
    }

    @Test()
    public void someStart(){
        System.out.println("Start");
        System.out.println(String.format("Instance: %d; Instance run: %d; Global run %d.", current_instance, run++, globalrun++));
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "someStart")
    public void x(){
        String[] a = {"a","b","c","d"};
        int i = 0;
        while( i < a.length && !a[i].equals(p)) i++;
        i = (i < a.length)? i + 1 : 0;
        System.out.println(p + ": " + i);
        System.out.println(String.format("Instance: %d; Instance run: %d; Global run %d.", current_instance, run++, globalrun++));
        Assert.assertEquals(i, n);
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "x", alwaysRun = true)
    public void someEnd(){
        System.out.println("End");
        System.out.println(String.format("Instance: %d; Instance run: %d; Global run %d.", current_instance, run++, globalrun++));
    }
}
```

and I get expected result (run tests with current data set):

```
Start
Instance: 2; Instance run: 0; Global run 0.

Start
Instance: 4; Instance run: 0; Global run 1.

Start
Instance: 1; Instance run: 0; Global run 2.

Start
Instance: 3; Instance run: 0; Global run 3.

c: 3
Instance: 2; Instance run: 1; Global run 4.

x: 0
Instance: 4; Instance run: 1; Global run 5.

a: 1
Instance: 1; Instance run: 1; Global run 6.

d: 4
Instance: 3; Instance run: 1; Global run 7.

End
Instance: 2; Instance run: 2; Global run 8.

End
Instance: 4; Instance run: 2; Global run 9.

End
Instance: 1; Instance run: 2; Global run 10.

End
Instance: 3; Instance run: 2; Global run 11.

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question gets closed.

Comment: when i try do this now, i get the message: _You can accept your own answer tomorrow_